# How to Use m4 when Generating C++ Header Files with Flex and Bison?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, m4

I have a question regarding the use of C++ m4 macros.  I am trying to compile someone else's code and in one of the header files there is a line that looks like:

```
b4_copyright(C++ Skeleton parser for LALR(1) parsing with Bison, 2002, 2003)
```

This of course returns an error when it tries to compile the code:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
```

The definition of `b4_copyright` in the c.m4 file from the install of bison is:

```
m4_define([b4_copyright],
[/* A Bison parser, made by GNU Bison b4_version.  */

/* $1

m4_text_wrap([Copyright (C) $2 Free Software Foundation, Inc.], [   ])

...

This special exception was added by the Free Software Foundation in
version 2.2 of Bison.  */])
```

I think the error happens when the header file is being generated by flex and bison.  For some reason when Bison goes through the parsed code, it doesn't suppress the output of the m4 macro (in this case, the b4_copyright) like it should.  When it creates the header file it leaves the lines from the stdout of the macros that it ran.  Why would it do this?

According to the c.m4 file (where the definition for b4_copyright is) the output should be suppressed. The c.m4 file uses definitions from m4sugar.m4 as well. These definitions are seemingly not applied anywhere in the c.m4 file however, because it's not using the m4_divert function (which is defined in m4sugar.m4) to suppress the output like I think it is supposed to .

Comment: I found the problem.  In the lex skeleton file that was being used to generate the code, the person before me had forgotten to add a m4_include for the c.m4 file.  Adding this fixed all of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is quite amazing: the user should never be exposed to these internal details, even if you try hard to!  In particular, you can do whatever you want with Flex, Bison should remain stable: it never needs to read Flex files.

So really, either your M4 installation is wrong, or someone played with your Bison skeleton files (which should never happen).  In any other case, it's a bug, and it should be reported to the proper list (bug-bison at gnu.org).